# Service-account.json file not found error

Tags: android, notifications

I'm migrating from HTTP to HTTP v1 for notification in android studio. have added Service-account.jason file to assets folder. But i'm not able to access the file while trying to send
notification.

getting below error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: service-account.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please review the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539295/service-account-json-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C318.7803