# service-account.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the access token , I'm doing everything exactly as described here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/tree/f75816cd181cdaf49401db3b3b52e4f20f629470/messaging , but I get the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: service-account.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
The service-account.json file is located here https://ibb.co/1ZPvQx9

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getAccessToken(): String {

    val googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
        .fromStream(FileInputStream("service-account.json"))
        .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
    googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken()
    return googleCredentials.accessToken.tokenValue
}
```

Comment: If you want to implement, Firebase sign-in with Google, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm trying to make a push notification, to do this I need to get the access token

Answer (score 1):

Please see below for my answer:

1. I had to move getAccessToken() to an Activity.  I put it in MainActivity.  I beieve you can leave it in the Messaging.java file.  Please see number 8.
2. I had to change the 'service-account.json' file name to 'serviceaccount.json'
3. I had to put the 'serviceaccount.json' in the 'raw' folder in the 'res' directory. If you don't have a 'raw' folder you can create one.
4. implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.7.0' in build.gradle
5. Do not use 'googleCredentials.getAccessToken()' because it will return null
6. I had to put the following in build.gradle in android{}

```
    //Put Exclude for google auth
        packagingOptions {
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
            //exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE")        
            //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE.txt")
            //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/license.txt")
            //exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/NOTICE")
            //exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/NOTICE.txt")
            //exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/notice.txt")
            //exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/ASL2.0")
            //exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
            exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
        }
```

7. Please see the code below.  This worked for me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static final String[] SCOPES = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging" };
    private GoogleCredentials googleCredentials;
    private InputStream jasonfile;
    private String beaerertoken;
    private String BEARERTOKEN;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        try {

            getAccessToken();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    private void getAccessToken() throws IOException {

       jasonfile = getResources().openRawResource(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("serviceaccount","raw",getPackageName()));


       new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

               try {

                  googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                           .fromStream(jasonfile)
                           .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
                   
                  googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();

                    beaerertoken = googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();
                   Log.d(TAG, "beaerertoken:  " + beaerertoken);

                    BEARERTOKEN = beaerertoken;

               } catch (IOException e) {

                   Log.d(TAG, "In error statement");
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }


           }
       }).start();



    }
}
```

8. If you want to leave getAccessToken() in the Messaging.java file please try the code below.

```
 // [START retrieve_access_token]
  public String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
                          
    InputStream fis = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("serviceaccount","raw",getPackageName()));
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(fis)
            .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
    googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken();
    return googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();
  }
  // [END retrieve_access_token]
```